# Cannot borrow as mutable more than once at a time in asynchronous code with a loop

Tags: loops, asynchronous, rust, lifetime

What is causing multiple simultaneous mutable borrows in this code? I suspect it has to do with the `<'a>` declared on the type `F` because if I remove the `'a` from the struct I am able to write the loop just fine.

[This works](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2e1fd908f1f2c343395c116e57032baf), but this does not:

```rust
struct F<'a> {
    i: u32,
    a: &'a mut u32,
}

impl<'a> F<'a> {
    async fn looper(self, x: &'a mut u32) -> F<'a> {
        let mut this = Some(self);

        loop {
            let me = this.take().unwrap();
            let new_me = me.inner(x).await;
            this.replace(new_me);
        }
    }

    async fn inner(self, x: &'a mut u32) -> F<'a> {
        *x += self.i;
        self
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1007fee30a926c402b923b503779c70b)

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*x` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/lib.rs:12:35
   |
12 |             let new_me = me.inner(x).await;
   |                                   ^ mutable borrow starts here in previous iteration of loop
```

Comment: It's not clear from your code why `x` and `F<'a>` both need the same lifetime, is that necessarily? For instance, https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=001441f7218683c67407d2f2ec731725 works fine

Comment: I need to specify that "x" has longer lifetime than F.a and F itself ... F.a is just a reference to something that is stored inside "x"

Comment: *F.a is just a reference to something that is stored inside "x"* - if `u32` is a stand-in for some other type, you can't keep a reference to something while a mutable reference also exists.

Comment: So, are you saying there are 2 simultaneous mut refs here -- one from F.a and and "x" being the other? If yes, how does the compiler figure out that F.a is a reference to something inside X ? I haven't specified that explicitly anywhere.

Comment: loganfsmyth's comment is the solution to your posted problem, I was simply warning you that the compiler will reject your code if you call `looper` while `self.a` references something in `x`.